# How to modify the "new" submenu in the Eclipse Navigator?

Tags: eclipse

I am pretty new to eclipse. I notice that depending on the Perspective I am in, the new submenu lists different items in it.  Is there a way to pick the items it lists (modifying the perspective) just using the eclipse interface? or am I needing to do a plugin of some sort to enable this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Window >> Customize Perspective
You should be on the Shortcuts tab and should see a dropdown called Submenus:
Make sure you have the "New" submenu selected and from there you can add New shortcuts.

Comment: Thanks it was an answer our java instructor didn't have a ready answer to.